# Ramda: Check if two arrays are equal

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm still learning functional programming in JavaScript and I enjoy using Ramda a lot.

I have two arrays. I want to check if they have the same values, independent of order. I thought this could be done with `equals`. But apparently

```
R.equals([1, 2], [2, 1]) // false
```

Is there an efficient way to check whether two arrays are equal? My arrays  constist of objects and can hold up to X * 10E4 values if that matters with 1 < X < 10.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work like that -- beyond the fact that the Ramda function is named [`equals`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#equals) and not `isEqual` -- is that Arrays are intrinsically ordered containers.  `[1, 2]` is materially *different* from `[2, 1]`.

The standard unordered container is the `Set`.  Unfortunately that is based on reference equality, so it could get multiple copies of items Ramda would think of as equal.  So the most obvious answer will not work properly:

```js
// ** Broken -- do not use **
const eqValues = (a1, a2) => R.equals(new Set(a1), new Set(a2))

console.log(eqValues(
  [{x: 1}, {x: 2}], 
  [{x: 1}, {x: 3}]
)) //=> false
console.log(eqValues(
  [{x: 1}, {x: 2}], 
  [{x: 2}, {x: 1}]
)) //=> true
```

because it would fail due to a length check in this case:

```js
console.log(eqValues(
  [{x: 1}, {x: 2}, {x: 2}], 
  [{x: 2}, {x: 1}]
)) //=> false, but should be true, since {x: 2} is the same as {x: 2}
```

Ramda does not expose its internal `_Set` type -- and perhaps it should -- but [it uses them](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.26.1/source/difference.js) in such functions as [`difference`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#difference), and through that in [`symmetricDifference`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#symmetricDifference).  These are appropriate functions for testing values whose value equality is in question.

So my answer would be similar to the one from bugs, but I would phrase it a bit differently:

```js
const eqValues = compose(isEmpty, symmetricDifference)

console.log(eqValues(
  [{x: 1}, {x: 2}], 
  [{x: 1}, {x: 3}]
)) //=> false
console.log(eqValues(
  [{x: 1}, {x: 2}], 
  [{x: 2}, {x: 1}]
)) //=> true
console.log(eqValues(
  [{x: 1}, {x: 2}], 
  [{x: 2}, {x: 1}, {x: 1}]
)) //=> true
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/ramda@0.26.1"></script><script>
const {compose, isEmpty, symmetricDifference} = ramda;   </script>
```

However, if you need to test multiplicities -- that is, `arr1` contains two copies of `{x: 42}` and `arr2` only has one, so they're different -- then I would use the answer from customcommander.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I fixed the error in my question. The objects in the arrays are all unique because of unique id's as values. So you answer should work, right?

Comment: _Arrays are intrinsically ordered containers_ this intuition for types in an untyped language like Javascript is rare here on SO. That's just my subjective view, though. +1

Comment: Your implementation is actually the only that passes. customcommander throws a false positive:

`const equalValues = (arr1, arr2) =>
  R.eqBy(R.countBy(R.identity), arr1, arr2);

equalValues([{ foo: 'bar', baz: null }, { hi: 'ho' }], [{ hello: 'world' }, { foo: 'bar', baz: null }])`

Comment: @J.Hesters: Yes, if the array elements are guaranteed to be unique, then this should work.  But then the first answer I gave would also work in that case.

Answer (score 6):

I would use [`eqBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#eqBy) with [`countBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#countBy):

You can use `countBy` to build a "profile" of your array:

```
countBy(identity, [1, 2]);
//=> {"1": 1, "2": 1}

countBy(identity, [2, 1]);
//=> {"1": 1, "2": 1}
```

Then you can compare the two profiles with `eqBy`:

```
eqBy(countBy(identity), [1,2], [2,1])
//=> true
```

Comment: Hmm, your solution throws a false positive:

`const equalValues = (arr1, arr2) =>
  R.eqBy(R.countBy(R.identity), arr1, arr2);

equalValues([{ foo: 'bar', baz: null }, { hi: 'ho' }], [{ hello: 'world' }, { foo: 'bar', baz: null }])`

Comment: For comparing objects the function in countBy needs to be more involved I’m afraid. One option is to produce unique signature for each.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to achieve this with Ramda

One that comes to mind is

```
R.length([1,2]) === R.length([2,1]) && R.isEmpty(R.symmetricDifference([1,2], [2,1]))
```

---

**edit**: using `R.difference` as opposed to `R.symmetricDifference` wouldn't work, as the first one only returns the elements in the first list that are not contained in the second list.

`R.difference([1,2], [2,1,3]) // -> []`